# ListView not getting updated after entry of elements in database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a `listview` and a `dialog`. I have to take three inputs from the `dialog` and implement it in the `listview` for which I have a `sqlitedatabase`. I am using a `customised adapter` for inserting the entries in the `listview`. But whenever I click on the `save button` after inserting the entries in the `dialog`, the `database` as well as the `listview` gets updated but when the `listview` is displayed on the screen the entries are not displayed for which I applied `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

The function of the `save button` :

```
save_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                selectedModel=new Model();
                selectedModel.setTask_title(task_Title.getText().toString());
                selectedModel.setTask_description(task_Description.getText().toString());
                selectedModel.setTask_date(task_Date.getText().toString());
                db.insertTask(selectedModel);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"model ="+selectedModel.getTask_title(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("Second Screen","list length before "+list.size());
                list=db.getAllTasks();

                Log.i("Second Screen","list length after "+list.size());
                Adapter adapter =( Adapter)getListView().getAdapter();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"model ="+selectedModel.getTask_title(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
```

The main class where I defined all the functionalities :

```
public class SecondScreen extends ListActivity implements AppCompatCallback,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private Toolbar bar;
private AppCompatDelegate delegate;
List<Model> list;
Model selectedModel;
AGSQLiteHelper db;
Adapter adapter;
private EditText task_Title,task_Description,task_Date;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    delegate=AppCompatDelegate.create(this,this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    delegate.setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen);
    bar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbarID);
    delegate.setSupportActionBar(bar);
    ActionBar ab=delegate.getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    db=new AGSQLiteHelper(this);
    db.onUpgrade(db.getWritableDatabase(),1,2);
    db.createTask(new Model("abcde","description abcde","19/11/12"));
    db.createTask(new Model("bcdese","description bcdese","18/12/12"));
    db.createTask(new Model("mnbv","description mnbv","2/11/10"));
    db.createTask(new Model("poiuy","description poiuy","1/5/6"));
    list=db.getAllTasks();
    adapter=new Adapter(this,R.layout.row,list);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onSupportActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {

}

@Override
public void onSupportActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {

}

@Nullable
@Override
public ActionMode onWindowStartingSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.add){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Add was clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(SecondScreen.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Dialog");
        Button save_button=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.saveButtonID);
        Button cancel_button=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelButtonID);

        task_Title=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.titleEditTextID);
        task_Description=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.descriptionEditTextID);
        task_Date=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dateEditTextID);

        dialog.show();

        save_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                selectedModel=new Model();
                selectedModel.setTask_title(task_Title.getText().toString());
                selectedModel.setTask_description(task_Description.getText().toString());
                selectedModel.setTask_date(task_Date.getText().toString());
                db.insertTask(selectedModel);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"model ="+selectedModel.getTask_title(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("Second Screen","list length before "+list.size());
                list=db.getAllTasks();

                Log.i("Second Screen","list length after "+list.size());
                Adapter adapter =( Adapter)getListView().getAdapter();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"model ="+selectedModel.getTask_title(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

        cancel_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });



    }


    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.done){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Done was clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

I have used `Log` and `Toast` to check whether the `listView` and `database` is getting updated or not.

The `customised adapter` class :

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {
Context context;
int layoutResourceID;
List<Model> data=null;
public Adapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID,List<Model> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceID, data);
    //super(context,layoutResourceID);
    this.layoutResourceID=layoutResourceID;
    this.context=context;
    this.data=data;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row=convertView;
    ModelHolder holder=null;

    if(row==null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceID, parent, false);
        holder = new ModelHolder();
        holder.t_title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tasktitleTextID);
        holder.t_descrip = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.taskdescriptionTextID);
        holder.t_date = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.taskdateTextID);

        row.setTag(holder);}

    else {
        holder=(ModelHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    //Model model=new Model();
    holder.t_title.setText(data.get(position).getTask_title());
    holder.t_descrip.setText(data.get(position).getTask_description());
    holder.t_date.setText(data.get(position).getTask_date());



    return row;
}

class ModelHolder{
    TextView t_title,t_descrip,t_date;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
save_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                selectedModel=new Model();
                selectedModel.setTask_title(task_Title.getText().toString());
                selectedModel.setTask_description(task_Description.getText().toString());
                selectedModel.setTask_date(task_Date.getText().toString());
                db.insertTask(selectedModel);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"model ="+selectedModel.getTask_title(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("Second Screen","list length before "+list.size());
                list.add(selectedModel);

                Log.i("Second Screen","list length after "+list.size());

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

Try this once

Comment: Ya, I already added `list=db.getAllTasks();` before `notifyDataSetChanged()`. It didn't work.

Comment: Adapter adapter =( Adapter)getListView().getAdapter();     
You are updating adapter again with the previous values of adapter, where is the list added to adapter again?

Comment: I commented out `Adapter adapter =( Adapter)getListView().getAdapter();` but still not working, can you please elaborate what should I do?

Comment: can you help me in one more thing, whenever I press the back button the entries which I enter through my dialog gets deleted after I open the app again, any suggestions for that?

Comment: that is what I was about to say, your database is not updated, kindly check if data is inserted in DB, because your previous logic was right but I think data is not inserted in DB, so your list is not updated, once your new entry is inserted you can use your previous logic. As that is the proper way of doing

Comment: Ya,I solved the back button issue by commenting out the `onUpgrade` method inside the `onCreate` method. Thanks for your help!